# Difference in arithmetic between @< and < in Prolog

Tags: prolog, comparison

The following queries both return true.

```
1 @< 2.
true
1 < 2.
true
```

In class we were told that `@<` *can do more than* `<` *because it can also do alphabetic comparison next to arithmetic comparison*. Because I thought this sounded like hogwash (why would you need two operators anyway if the one includes another's behaviour) I did some basic testing. For me it seemed more logical that `@<` *only* does alphabetic testing in which case digits are nothing more than an extension to the alphabet. Because

```
9 @< a.
true
Z @< a.
true
```

it would seem that the 'order of the alphabet' is something like this (excluding diacritics and special characters):

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWQYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyz
```

The advantage of using `<` over `@<` would then be that the former first solves the equations on both sides, whereas the latter does nothing more than a string comparison:

```
(2/5) < (1/2).
true
(2/5) @< (1/2).
false
```

Even though the explanation above seems logical (and tested) to me, I am not sure because it was only briefly introduced and faulty or at least ambiguously explained (see the italic quote above). My question is, then, are my assumptions correct and is `@<` nothing more than a string comparison, whereas `<` actually solves both sides and then compares? *Does `<` actually do a number comparison after solving both sides, or does it fall back to string comparison?* (Which, after solving both sides to a real number would yield the same result as an arithmetic solution. If so, what about irrational numbers?) And is my assumption of the 'alphabet including digits' also correct, or am I missing some important details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@<` compares according to the standard order of terms; `<` compares arithmetic expressions. Neither can do "more" or "less" than the other, because they do different things. You could say that there are cases where `@<` can be used but `<` cannot, but there are also cases where the two will give you opposite answers.

The SWI-Prolog documentation is one place to get details on this. The `@<` compares using the [standard order of terms](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder), along with all other such predicates: `==`, `\==`, `@<`, `@=<`, `@>`, `@>=`. The most interesting one here is probably the predicate `compare/3`. But yes, standard order of terms defines an order for *any* term you might have in a Prolog program, including free variables.

On the other hand, [arithmetic comparisons](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=arithpreds) *evaluate* the arithmetic expressions on both sides, and compare their values. Important is that on both sides, the expression should evaluate to a number, you cannot have variables left there. In other words:

```
?- X @< 1.
true. % because free variables come before all other terms

?- X < 1.
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
% An exception is thrown because X is not a valid arithmetic expression
```

This was an example where `@<` can give you an answer, "The variable `X` sorts before the integer `1` in the standard order of terms", while `<` just tells you "cannot do this" (which neither "yes" nor "no").

Another example:

```
?- 1 + 2 < 5.
true.

?- 1 + 2 @< 5.
false.
```

This is an example where the two comparisons give you opposite answers. If you use `<`, you get the answer "1 + 2 is less than 5", while if you use `@<` you get the answer "The term `+(1, 2)` does not sort before the integer `5` in the standard order of terms". This is because all compound terms sort *after* all numbers.

This means that you cannot use for example `sort/2`, which sorts according to the standard order of terms, to sort numbers or arithmetic expressions. First, according to ISO, all floating numbers precede all integers (someone correct me if I am wrong on this). Then, SWI-Prolog has support for rational numbers, in the form `Numerator rdiv Denominator`, for example `1 rdiv 2` means "one half". Because this is currently just a compound term:

```
?- 1 rdiv 2 < 1.
true.

?- 1 rdiv 2 @< 1.
false.
```

As for "irrational numbers" from your question, are you sure you don't mean "rational"?

Finally, if you use standard order of terms comparisons, make sure you understand what is the *type* of the things you are comparing! Again, from the [SWI-Prolog documentation](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder):

> Variables < Numbers < Strings < Atoms < Compound terms

Number and atom:

```
?- 9 @< '0'.
true.
```

String and atom:

```
?- "Z" @< 'A'.
true.
```

Variable and string:

```
?- Z @< "A".
true.
```

Two compound terms with the same arguments, but `'+' @< '-'`:

```
?- 1 + 2 @< 1 - 2.
true.
```

So it is not *just* about some kind of basic string comparison, the type of the terms you are comparing are important.